# Beautiful Soup o selectores en Python

Tags: python, css, xpath, beautifulsoup

Buenas

Para mis proyectos de scraping he venido utilizando una combinación de selenium con beautiful soup. Una vez convertido el html en plain text, utilizaba `.find()` y `.find_all()` para ir moviendome por la info que quería.

La cosa es que ahora que me he familiarizado más con los selectores, del tipo

```
element(by.id("id"));
element(by.css("#id"));
element(by.xpath("//*[@id='id']"))
```

Mi pregunta es, cual es la diferencia? Para qué usar BSoup si puedes localizar por selectores? Porque alguna diferencia sustancial en términos de parsing debe haber.
Aparte, en cuanto a codificación, qué sistema es más rápido, o más robusto.

Comment: Hola Puppet. Yo creo que esto está basado en opiniones. ¿Por qué usar un lenguaje/tecnologia u otro? Muchos lenguajes pueden hacer lo mismo pero de distintas maneras. Quizá sea la sintaxis, o la velocidad o un gusto personal irracional. Mira [ask] y [help/on-topic] para aprender a hacer preguntas validas y de calidad. un saludo

Comment: Mi pregunta no es cual prefieres. Mi pregunta es qué hace BSoup que no hagan los selectores. Porque si puedes sacar el texto directamente con los selectores no entiendo la necesidad de parsear primero con BS4 y luego buscar. Mi pregunta adicional es de qué manera se hace un código más robusto o rápido. Tu respuesta puede ser que no hay diferencias y que es cuestión de gustos, pero eso no invalida la pregunta realizada.